# Problem with using the REST-ful link_to while using it in a mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-url

I strongly feel its a silly error and I'm somehow not able to see through it. I'm trying to use this piece of code in the view of my mailer.

```
<p><%= link_to 'here', unsubscribe_path(:email => "a@b.com") %></p>
```

And I've defined a named route in my routes file :

```
map.unsubscribe '/unsubscribe', :controller => :users, :action => :unsubscribe
```

So when I send my email this is the link I get:

```
http://b.comonly_pathtruecontrollerusersactionunsubscribe/
```

Any ideas ? Thanks !

**EDIT**

Here's the view:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
Hi, <br />

You have an alert for : <%= @alert.name %>. <br />

Here is some brief information about it: <br />

<%= @alert.details %><br /><br />
<br />Thank You,<br />
</p>
<p>
Click <p><%= link_to 'here', unsubscribe_path(:email => "a@b.com") %></p> to unsubscribe</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the mailer:

```
class Alert < ActionMailer::Base

def send(alert, email)
  @subject = "hi"
  @recipients = "xyz@mail.com"
  @from = "xyz@mail.com"
  @sent_on = Time.now
  @content_type = "text/html"

  @alert = alert
  @email = email
end
```

end

Comment: Why don't just use `link_to 'here', 'http://xxx.com/unsubscribe?email=a@b.com'`

Comment: Yes that would work. But its not a good practice to hard code urls like that, is it? Thanks anyways, will have to use it until I get a solution to keep it REST-ful.

Comment: Please can you include in your question how you're generating your email. The route is ok so it must be your notifier or template.

Comment: Sure Mark. I've added it now.

Comment: Might want to edit your real email address out of the code here...

Comment: Have made small additional edit to my answer which should fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a working template, I can't say for sure why yours isn't working but try generating the url in the notifier.

```
# notifier
def new_message_email(response)
    I18n.locale = response.recipient.language
    subject      I18n.t(:you_have_received_new_message_from_sender, :sender => response.sender.login)
    from         "info@domain.com"
    recipients   response.recipient.email
    content_type "text/html"
    sent_on      Time.now
    body         :sender_login => response.sender.login, :recipient_login => response.recipient.login
  end

#template
= word_wrap "Hi #{@recipient_login}."
= word_wrap ""
%p
= word_wrap "You have received a new personal message from #{@sender_login}.", :line_width => 60
= word_wrap "Click #{link_to 'here', account_inbox_url} to view your domain.com message inbox.", :line_width => 60
= word_wrap "If the above URL does not work try copying and pasting it into your browser. If you continue to have problems, please feel free to contact us at support@domain.com.", :line_width => 60
```

You will need to generate a url, rather than a path.

```
eg:
account_path => /account
account_url => http://domain.com/account
```

edit:
this should work:

```
#notifier
body         :unsubscribe_url => unsubscribe_url(:email => "a@b.com")

#template
= word_wrap "Click #{@unsubscribe_url} to unsubscribe.", :line_width => 60
```

(see above example for how this all fits together)

Answer (score 1):

Does this unsubscribe_url (or _path) work in any other view?

The returned value looks like a something made from a Hash converted to String. Try to call .inspect on the object returned by "link_to()" - maybe there will be some clue?

Maybe something redefined a link_to method somewhere in your code? Use "grep def.*link_to" - maybe some clues will be there?

A test may be useful in this and later cases. Here is an example (however this is what I use in rails 1, but I hope this does not differ too much in your rails version).

```
def test_routing
  assert_routing '/unsubscribe', {:controller => 'user', :action => 'unsubscribe'}
  assert_recognizes Hash[:controller => 'user', :action => 'unsubscribe'],
      {:path=>'/unsubscribe', :method => :get},
      {"email"=>"a@example.com"}
  # ..and so on
end
```